# Certificate for Terminal Services authentication on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I like to remote into my Vista Ultimate desktop computer when I'm not at home, or am using a laptop in another room. The Remote Desktop Connection utility on domain-joined  Windows Vista machines won't let you use saved credentials to connect to an unauthenticated computer (you get an annoying error message: "Your system administrator does not allow the use of saved credentials to log on to the remote computer *[computername]* because its identity is not fully verified"). I'd like to resolve the problem by assigning a certificate (self-signed or otherwise) to Terminal Services, as suggested in [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2007/07/31/problems-using-saved-credentials-with-vista-rdp-clients-and-above.aspx) from the TS team blog. Unfortunately, the `tsconfig.msc` snapin isn't available on Vista, as the blog entry notes. What other options do I have for adding a certificate, or otherwise allowing me to use saved credentials?

Comment: the tsconfig.msc snapin doesnt seem to be on xp pro either...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by Group Policy on a Vista machine. I'm not going to take credit for this, so here's an article: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6166676.html.

The only next issue may be that the domain does not trust the certificate because it does not come from a recognised provider. I suppose you could ask for your internal CA to issue a certificate for it, but I doubt they'll allow it.

If this happens, then [logmein](http://logmein.com/) as maniac13 mentioned is probably the way to go (unless they've blocked that too, as some organisations have been known to do).

You must have an exceptionally complicated user/pass combo for this to be a pressing issue!

Comment: great link to article.  thanks!    also, after accepting the RDP FIPS certificate, you can see the certificate by running mmc.exe  and then adding the "Certificates" snap-in  (to see machine-wide cert store).

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to help you with your issue here, but I can recommend using [logmein](http://logmein.com) as an alternative. With this option you won't even need a static IP address, all you need is a web browser and you are set. and its free.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the free version of Hamachi, or what is now called "[LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/free/)"  will do it without any firewall configuration required.   It will create a highly encrypted tunnel that won't likely be exploited (especially if you use a long password greater than 12 chars).  There are also some open source Hamachi look-a-likes such as [P2PVPN](http://p2pvpn.org/) or [Wippien](http://www.wippien.com/) , Remobo, and some others, including the difficult to configure [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net/) .   Also, with the tunnel open you will be able to RDP to the machine , bypassing the firewall, with zero firewall config required.